# 3 sets of 3 wires for 2 light switches

Tags: bathroom, light

I'm trying to replace my old light switches for dimmer switches but there are 3 sets of 3 wires in the box but only 2 switches were there. I only have the 1 light and the fan in my bathroom (and yes I know that a dimmer switch is stupid for a fan but it was a 2 pack for cheap) when my bf first hooked them up the lights and fan would stay on constantly because he had another wire connecting the switches together for some reason. I took that wire off and the switches still don't turn anything on and off but the light is out but the fan is still going I just need help to know what's going on.

Comment: We need pictures of how things were connected before your bf changed things, and then pictures now of how things are hooked up.  Without pictures, it's impossible to identify what's going on.  Rule #1 of Home Improvement Stack Exchange wiring change questions - take "before" pictures.

Comment: Please provide clear photos or a wiring diagram. It's very difficult to assist from this vague description. Note that dimmers aren't often rated for fan use (and vice versa).

Comment: You are not qualified to perform that work, and might kill your self. Call your BF back. At bare minimum. you need a tool called Non Contact phase tester, to guide you which wires a dangerous to touch.

Comment: A dimmer switch for a fan isn’t just stupid, it’s wrong. You’ll likely damage the dimmer, the Dan of both! Put that switch back!

Comment: For cheap and electrical devices should never be in the same sentence.  Bad stuff(fire, death) can and does happen.  Two switches and three cables might mean one cable is for/coming from power/panel.

Comment: Do you mean 3 cables containing 3 wires each?  Is one of them bare or green (that'd be ground)?  It's not that "dimmer on a fan" is dumb, it's *dangerous* and will start a fire.

Answer (score 1):

For a box with 2 switches there should be 3 cables in the box
(3 cables, each cable has 3 wires, black, white, bare copper.

Start with the breaker to the circuit turned off.  Remove the switches/ dimmers.

the 3 bare copper wires should be twisted together and held with a wire nut. Then tucked into the back of the box.

The 3 white wires should also be twisted together and a wire nut capping the bare copper exposed ends.

Now you have some investigating.

one black wire goes to the fan.

One black wire goes to the light

one black wire is the hot lead from the breaker box. you need to find that one.

If you do not have a [non contact tester](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099SJ6469) you need to buy or borrow one and know how to use it.

with the 3 black wire separated and individually capped, turn the breaker to that circuit back on.  Use the tester to find which of the black wires is hot.
Mark it with some tape. This is constant HOT.

Of the other 2 black wires one goes to the fan the other to the light.

Turn the breaker back off.  Twist together one of the unknown black wires and the previously marked constant HOT wire. ( you can just twist a wire nut on the 2 wires to join them . This is temporary.)

turn the breaker back on.  whatever device, light or fan that is on is the termination for the unknown black wire you have twisted to the Hot wire.
The non working device is fed by the other black wire.

Now you know what wires got to the fan, the light and come from the breaker.

Take the wire to the light and attach it to one of the screws, or "load" wire from a dimmer or a switch.

Attach the black wire to the fan to a screw of a switch. ( do not use a dimmer)

Now you have just the HOT wire. You need to "pigtail" or make 2 shorter wires. Preferably black or wires you need to make black. ( about 6 to 8 inches is good.)

Connect the 2 short wires and the HOT wire together and cap with a wire nut.

Now you have 2 remaining wires. one each get attached to the switch and the dimmer .

Everything is tucked neatly into the box and the switches/ dimmer are screwed into the box.

Turn the breaker back on.  Install the trim plate and you are done.